# Stuck in creating a Simple procedure in MySQL [IF statement]

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

I want to create a procedure in MySql using IF statement that would let me show the names of all students who's average is above 70 when I give the id of  a student as IN parameter.

Is it possible to give many student Ids at a time and access more results using CALL and SELECT?

**Student Table:**

> **id, name, major, avg, status**
>    '33', 'Vera Violet', NULL, '92',
>   'UNCL'
>    '94', 'Pat Pink', 'POLS',   '93', 'UNCL'
>     '101', 'Bob Blue',  'ECON', '73', 'UNCL'
>   '102', 'Wyatt White', 'GEOG', '64', 'UNGR'
>   '302', 'Yolanda Yellow', 'HIST', '64', 'UNGR'
>     '403', 'Bryan Black',
>   'ECON', '87', 'GRAD'
>    '576', 'Ruby Rose', 'ECON', '77', 'UNCL'
>   '992', 'Greg Green', 'COMM', '86', 'GRAD'

**Here is what I tried: (But didn't worked)**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sort_Students_By_Avg( IN student_Id INT(11), OUT student_Name VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN 
DECLARE student_Avg INT(11); 
SELECT avg INTO student_Avg
FROM student
WHERE id=student_Id; 

IF (student_Avg > 70)
THEN SET student_Name = student.name;
END IF;
END $$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem particularly useful, but a procedure would look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sort_Students_By_Avg (
    IN in_student_Id INT(11),
    OUT out_student_Name VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT s.name INTO out_student_name
    FROM student s
    WHERE s.id = in_student_Id AND s.avg > 70; 
END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy. Is it possible to give many student Ids at a time and access more results using CALL and SELECT?